# change windows 7 frame color for a specific instance of chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I've got a number of apps that I run inside chrome, and would like to be able to change the windows frame color for a specific one to help it stand out in my stack of open windows.  Any suggestions on how to do this?  I'm not sure whether this would be more easily done in the win7 desktop/explorer subsystem, or whether chrome can be told to change it's color scheme/theme per window...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome handles the color or theme from the file **VisualElementManifest** from its installation location. This color will be applied to all windows that relates to chrome and it is not possible to have separate manifest for app-level window frame changes in Chrome.

Hope this helps!